# Can I create properties with a public getter and private setter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to use properties for my instance variables, but in many cases, I only want the class itself to have access to the setter.  I was hoping I could do something like this:

Foo.h:

```
@interface Foo {
  NSString *bar;
}
@property (readonly) NSString *bar;
@end
```

Foo.m:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@interface Foo ()
@property (copy) NSString *bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar;
@end
```

But this generates a warning:

```
Foo.m:4: warning: property ‘bar’ attribute in ‘Foo’ class continuation does not match class ‘Foo’ property
```

I can see what it's complaining about, but it still seems like a useful idiom.  Is there some other way to accomplish this without writing my own setters?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but the redeclaration of `@property bar` in the class extension must match the original declaration except for readwrite vs. readonly. So this will work:

Foo.h

```
@interface Foo {
  NSString *bar;
}
@property (copy,readonly) NSString *bar;
@end
```

Foo.m:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@interface Foo ()
@property (copy,readwrite) NSString *bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar;
@end
```

(recall that the default is `assign` for properties, not `copy`).

Comment: Huh, that never occurred to me since 'copy' is otherwise irrelevant to the getter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When Barry says "the default is retain for properties" he means that retain should be specified like this:

```
@property (retain) NSDate *endDate;
```

If they are left like this:

```
@property NSDate *endDate;
```

assign is assumed by the compiler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant exactly what he said, but you're right—`assign` is the default, not `retain`. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW27